# Run a method only at Spring Application Context startup?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I need to run a method after the Spring Application Context of my web app has started up.   I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158336/is-there-a-way-to-run-a-method-class-only-on-tomcat-startup) but it refers to Java Servlet startup, and none of the Spring stuff has run at that point.

Is there a "SpringContext.onStartup()" method I can hook into?

Comment: What you want is an `ApplicationListener`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use something like the following code:

```
@Component
public class StartupListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(final ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    // do your stuff here 
  }
}
```

Of course StartupListener will need to be within the component scan's reach

Take note however that if your application uses multiple contexts (for example a root context and a web context) this method will be run once for each context.

Answer (score 4):

You can write listener like this:

```
@Component
public class SpringContextListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> {
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("ApplicationListener");
    };
}
```

Just add component scan path like this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Better application events in Spring Framework 4.2](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2#annotation-driven-event-listener)

```
@Component
public class MyListener {

    @EventListener
    public void handleContextRefresh(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Annotate a method of a managed-bean with @EventListener to automatically register an ApplicationListener matching the signature of the method. @EventListener is a core annotation that is handled transparently in a similar fashion as @Autowired and others: no extra configuration is necessary with java config and the existing < context:annotation-driven/> element enables full support for it.