# Start Listener AFTER Tomcat startup?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, listener

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158336/is-there-a-way-to-run-a-method-class-only-on-tomcat-startup) code to start a listener before Tomcat initializes, but it has a while loop in it that will check a database every 5 seconds for changes. Is there any way that I can skip the looping part of that until my web service has been started completely, then trigger the loop to begin checking?

**EDIT**: Meant `listener` and not `Servlet`

**EDIT2**: Code below

```
public class DatabaseChecker implements ServletContextListener {

final static String URL = "redacted";
final static String USER = "redacted";
final static String PASS = "redacted";

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {

    Vector<String> completedJobs = new Vector<String>();

    try {
        while(true) {   // loop to always check & notify
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println("Checker running ...");
            // completedJobs = selectCompletedJobs();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("ServletContextListener destroyed");

}
```

}

Comment: That's just wrong. The while loop is going to prevent the context listener from ever finishing, and thus your application will probably remain in a not-initialized state. The sleeping-busy while loop should probably be happening in a separate background thread. Like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691132/how-to-run-a-background-task-in-a-servlet-application

Comment: @Gimby that worked!!! Wanna make that an answer so I can give you that checkmark? ;)

Comment: the fact that another question+answer entirely answers yours makes your question a duplicate. Hence BalusC correctly did the paperwork.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The `ServletContext` allows you to add attributes, which is a global context shared between the `ServletContextListener` and the services running in the servlet.

You can have the `ServletContextListener` wait for the web service by polling for an attribute.

When your web service is ready, it can add the attribute to the `ServletContext`.

Now when your `ServletContextListener` finds the attribute, it can proceed.

Comment: I edited the OP to reflect my code. Should I make changes there or in my `web.xml`?

Comment: These are code changes. You have to add the polling to `DatabaseChecker`.